# Uploading files to a website with javascript

Tags: javascript, python

First of all, I have no experience and very, VERY, basic knowledge in web development. So please bear with me a bit.

I have written a python function to upload files to S3. Works like a charm for all my non web scripts and applications. I now need to be able to use this function on a website, via an upload button. I have the browse button and the button (or whatever the correct terminology for that is):

```
    <div id="uploader">
        <input type="file" id="uploadme" />
        <input type="button" id="clickme" value="Upload!" />
    </div>
```

Now, I was planning to use JavaScript to call the Python function and upload the file. My questions are:

1. How do I do this in JavaScript with the 2 buttons I have above?
2. How do I check which user will the python function run in the server? Something among the lines of running `whoami`.
3. Is there a better and/or easier way of doing this?

Comment: You don't - Browsers are sandboxed and don't have direct access to files on either the PC or the server (so you can't run a local script from a browser)

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423456) will help you

Answer (score 0):

On the javascript side, the way you get the file is by accessing the file object. There are multiple ways to do this. MDN does a great job explaining it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

On question 2, you can use the os library in python. I am assuming you are running your python script in linux or OSX.

`import os
os.getenv('USER') #this should return the username from the environment variable`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Input elements `<input type="file">` are just calling the internal browser interface to the OS. This will then open the OS file picker dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can place form in a frame and upload it.
Or html file object:
developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications