# Preview Excel or CSV data before upload (AJAX maybe?)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, excel, xls

I'm creating a php web app and I want the users to be able to upload an excel (xls or xlsx) file or csv and then select which columns hold which data (ex. 'select sku column', select price column etc).  I think want to make the user preview the first row of the spreadsheet that they are uploading to verify they've picked the correct column for each item, before they upload the spreadsheet (which will read and write all the information from the file into a mysql table.

Is this possible with AJAX or something else?

Comment: Thanks Mark!  Unfortunately, this is what I assumed.

Comment: Already answered by http://stackoverflow.com/a/10019863/453605

Comment: @travis someone else is already doing this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2015/01/28/design-and-implementation-of-csvexcel-upload-for-saas/

Answer (score 0):

You can parse csv files in the browser before uploading (easy). For excel files, http://oss.sheetjs.com appears to parse XLS and XLSX files in the browser.