# How to read the csv file and do validation for the csv Header columns in Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, csv

I have a program where I'm reading the CSV file and validating the multiple CSV files header columns where columns Header count should be the same and columnsHeader name should be same (if it does not match, show some error message)

I've done validation in python but I don't know how to do validate in javascript/jquery. I want to do it from Html file

**Python program for validation:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("Loading the root file")
    return render_template("upload.html")
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'input/')
        print("target-",target)

        if not os.path.isdir(target):
            os.mkdir(target)

abs_path_files=[]
    for file in request.files.getlist("source_fileName"):
            print("file-",file)
            filename = file.filename
            print("filename-",filename)
            destination = "/".join([target, filename])
            print("destination-",destination)
            file.save(destination)
            print("file>",file)
            tempFile = os.path.abspath(destination)
            abs_path_files.append(tempFile)
            print("abs_path_files - " ,abs_path_files)
            global files_list
            files_list=abs_path_files
            print("files_list-",files_list)
    return redirect('/compute',)

@app.route("/compute")# Here we are performing the Header columns Validation 
def compute():
    dataFrames=[]
    for f in files_list:
        dataFrame=pd.read_csv(f)
        dataFrames.append(dataFrame)
    col_in_files = set([",".join(list(f.column.values)) for f in dataFrames])
    if len(col_in_files)==1:
       # After validation it will go for the other computations
    .......................................................
```

**Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> upload </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Large Data Generation</h1> 
<form id = "upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="file-selector">
            <p> 
                <strong>Source File: </strong>
                <input id="source_fileName" type="file" name="source_fileName" accept="csv/*" multiple />
            </p> 
        </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Data" id="upload-button"  >
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I see hardly any validation in the python.

Comment: @mplungjan its just a columns header validation in compute function

Comment: @mplungjan I have a very big program and lots of validation and compuation but i'm not getting it how to do it from using javascript that's why i ask this question

Comment: @mplungjan that doesn't help even i have searched on internet before coming here its all about validation for the extension  or how to validate csv file ....not there content i have already did it in my html as i said i have less knowledge of UI suff so i was asking?

Comment: What else do you need? If you cannot use the dupes, then how can we help?

Comment: This has an answer that loops over the file before uploading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019679/how-to-preprocess-a-local-csv-file-before-uploading-to-a-server

Comment: @mplungjan sir suppose i have multiple csv file in which it have different Header columns number or name so i just want to validate it before going for forward to my other operations if it does not match then it will show some error meassge these all thing i have done with python program that why i have pasted that piece of code so it help others to get how to do it from Javascript

Comment: there is 0 information in the python program as to what validation you want. SO is not a translation service. Please go to an e-lance site or similar. We expect you show what effort you have done and specific questions about where you are stuck. Please read [ask]